# Moderncv : put the homepage in bold

Tags: moderncv

I'd like to do this:

```
\homepage{ \textbf{www.adress.com} }
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do for putting the homepage in bold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to define a bold-faced variation of `\httplink` internally used to typeset the homepage; this bold-faced version is then used in patching the `\makecvtitle` command; here's an example using the `classic` theme:

```
\documentclass{moderncv} 
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatother
\newcommand*{\bfhttplink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{http://#2}{\bfseries#2}}%
    {\href{http://#2}{\bfseries#1}}}
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\httplink{\@homepage}}{\bfhttplink{\@homepage}}{}{}
\makeatletter
}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\homepage{www.adress.com}
\email{some-email@mail.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

It's not easy to personalize this model.

Moreover, I think I need to install the expl3 package, and it's not in Miktex...

Comment: @Stef sorry about that; in my updated answer I changed to the `etoolbox` package which should be already installed in your system.